# Can we create an object in java without a class?

Tags: java

If you can please help me understand if this is possible to create an object in java without having a class.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? In Java an object is an instance of a class.

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible with Java. Class is the primitive structure to generate Object. We need a Class to generate object. So, for the above code, i don't think there is a solution.

Comment: Somewhere I read around the below topics, but not having clear explanation to those. Is this related anyways? Using new keyword
Using new instance
Using clone() method
Using deserialization
Using newInstance() method of Constructor class

Comment: @somitr, all those approaches still create an object, and all objects have _some_ class (even if that class is `Class`). The only things that don't have a class are primitives, and primitives aren't objects.

Comment: You can easily find the answer on this question, if you first would look for understanding what exactly are *classes* and *objects*. First, it's always good idea, to try to look up something on your own, and then, if you have a specific problem of understanding, come and ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, it's either a primitive or an instance of a class.

Comment: There is one more thing: object [can be](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) an instance of *array*, which is not *the* class.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Arrays have classes too. For example `System.out.println(new int[4].getClass());` just printed `class [I`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I think we can consider it as a *special* type, which is not really *the* class. It's rather a special construct, and yes, getClass() definitely returns the runtime class.. but JLS also differentiates between class and array, explicitly.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri It’s correct what you say. It’s a debate about words.

Comment: @OleV.V. It's actually contradictory and blurry.. [class literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) implies array types as well, but object [is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) defined as an instance of class or an array. Definitely not super clear.. as several other points in JLS.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Objects are a copy of Class (or better - instance of it).

So there can't be objects without classes.

---

But there is a predefined class *Object* which all classes inherit and therefore all objects are of type *Object*.
Maybe you can try

```
Object myObj = new Object();
```

if that helps for you